# Python: How do I translate testing data tables from Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, datatable, gherkin, python-behave

I'm new to Python. I currently have this code in Javascript (using Cypress) but unfortunately, I had issues with the iframe using Firefox so we switched to Selenium (with Python) to run the test case. I tried to search for the equivalent of this for few hours already but no luck. What is the equivalent of this script to Python? I am writing in BDD as well. Not sure how to handle data tables in Python.

I used `match case` for Python but I got stuck when handling data tables with `hashes()` or `forEach()` in Python. Please help. :(

Javascript:

```
And (‘step title', (firstInput, dataTable)=>{
    switch (firstInput) {
        case 'First Case':
            dataTable.hashes().forEach(elem =>{
                if(elem.titleOfDataTable == 'First Data'){
                    <someActions>
                }else if(elem.titleOfDataTable == 'Second Data'){
                    <someActions>
                }else if(elem.titleOfDataTable == 'Third Data'){
                    <someActions>
                }else{
                    throw new Error(<someMessage>)
                }
            })
            break;

            default:
                <defaultActions>
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use if/elif/else statements and a `for` loop as such (assuming that elem is a dictionary/JSON):

```
def test(first_input, data_table):
    if (first_input == 'First Case'):
        for elem in data_table.hashes():
            if elem['titleOfDataTable]' == 'First Data':
                <some actions>
            elif elem['titleOfDataTable'] == 'Second Data':
                <some other actions>
            elif elem['titleOfDataTable'] == 'Third Data':
                <some more actions>
            else:
                raise ValueError("Unknown title: " + elem['titleOfDataTable'])
     else:
         <default actions>

And('step title', test)  # <- modify this line according to the Python API of your test application
```

Comment: Hello @Green绿色 thank you for the answer! :) I tried this one, no error in the script editor but I'm getting this error when I run "step_impl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'titleOfDataTable'"

Comment: "step_impl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data_table'"

Comment: Whoops. Got it now. Thank you so much @Green绿色  :) :) :)